# Expected a list of items but got type "QuerySet; BaseSerializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting create a read-only serializer as described here in the DRF docs where a custom `to_representation()` is implemented:

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#read-only-baseserializer-classes

When the serializer is validated with the `users` queryset the following error is raised:

- `Expected a list of items but got type "QuerySet"`

It's confusing as to why this error is being raised as it seems permissible that a QuerySet can be passed into the serializer with a `many=True` keyword argument to serialize each instance within the QuerySet.

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects

If the QuerySet is coerced into a list such as `data=list(users)`, a different error is raised:

- `NotImplementedError: to_internal_value() must be implemented`

How should this issue be tackled for the error to be resolved?

```
class AccountsEndpoint(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        query_string = request.query_params.copy()
        if 'search' in query_string:
            if query_string['search']:
                users = get_user_model().posted.by_name(query_string['search'])
                if not users:
                    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                users = get_user_model().posted.by_name("")
            serializer = UserListingSerializer(data=users, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                return Response(data=serializer.data)
        action = query_string.pop("action")[0]
        if action == "login":
            serializer = LoginSerializer
        else:
            serializer = RegisterSerializer
        serialized_object = serializer(data=query_string, partial=True)
        if serialized_object.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(data=serialized_object.validated_data)
```

```
class UserListingSerializer(BaseSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if instance:
            object = {
                'name': str(instance),
                'profile': {
                    'url': reverse("authors:profile", kwargs={"id": instance.id}),
                    'signed_up': instance.date_joined.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").lstrip("0"),
                    'last_login': instance.last_login.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").lstrip("0"),
                    'total_posts': instance.post_count
                }
            }
            return object
```

Comment: I discovered that `to_internal_value()` must be implemented regardless of a read vs a read/write serializer. In my case of just needing the serializer to read the stored data I returned the QuerySet:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    return data
```